# GNU LD - invalid subsystem type Windows

Tags: c++, batch-file, linker, ld

when i tray to run a Windows batch file from application (wxWidgets C++) GNU LD show error

```
C:\..path..\bin/ld.exe: invalid subsystem type Windows
```

and when double click on the same Windows batch file, GNU LD Work!

**LD.bat**

```
@echo off 

Set PATH=C:\AAA\BBB\GCC\bin

"C:\AAA\BBB\GCC\bin\g++.exe" -L"C:\AAA\BBB\GCC\lib\gcc_lib" -o "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test.exe" "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test.obj" "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test.res" -s -mthreads -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxbase30u ... -mwindows -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -finput-charset=utf-8 -Wl,--gc-sections -Os 2> "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test.log"
```

**App.cpp**

```
wxArrayString output;
wxArrayString errors;
wxString CMD;
CMD = "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Test.bat";
wxExecute (CMD, output, errors);
```

If batch file executed by the application ==> Test.log show error.

If batch file executed by double click ==> Test.log show NO error.

The problem is fixed by removing **-mwindows** flag, but the executable not linked as GUI as you know.. so whats wrong with GNU LD ?

Comment: Compare environment differences between two of launch modes.

Comment: no, in my case environment its not the issue, its the same, and even testing with different environments LD cannot linking with "-mwindows" flag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION :** After hours of searching.. i understand if your path contain the word `Windows` "%PATH%\Windows\.." GNU LD show error!, yes its a bug.

So **just rename your folder** from `Windows` to `Win`.